# React Native com.reactnativecommunity.viewpager.FragmentAdapter.<init> ( android ANR)

Tags: java, android, react-native

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.<init> (FragmentStateAdapter.java:102)
  at com.reactnativecommunity.viewpager.FragmentAdapter.<init> (FragmentAdapter.java:19)
  at com.reactnativecommunity.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager.createViewInstance (ReactViewPagerManager.java:58)
  at com.reactnativecommunity.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager.createViewInstance (ReactViewPagerManager.java:40)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createViewInstance (ViewManager.java:140)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView (ViewManager.java:77)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView (NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:282)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute (UIViewOperationQueue.java:194)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run (UIViewOperationQueue.java:908)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches (UIViewOperationQueue.java:1025)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600 (UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$2.runGuarded (UIViewOperationQueue.java:983)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run (GuardedRunnable.java:31)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8212)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

**My problem should be caused by it, but I don't know the specific reason. Can anyone please help me and how should I solve this problem;**

package.json

```
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: This library is old and was not updated from long time. Try using some one else.

Comment: This library is old and was not updated from long time. Try using some one else.

Comment: I have found the component library of **react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked**, but it doesn't have a ts version, so I can't use it;

Comment: Finally, I used the components provided by React native for secondary packaging. The usage is the same as react-native-scrollable-tab-view, and finally solved this problem.